# Why do I not have to implement the Any trait for a type even though it is a required?

Tags: rust

When defining a trait, my understanding is that trait names on the right side of the `:` are required any time the left side is implemented. If so, why does the following compile:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Trait: Any {}

struct Thing {}

impl Trait for Thing {}
```

The following does not compile (which matches my understanding of what is correct)

```
trait RequiredTrait {}
trait Trait: RequiredTrait {}

struct Thing {}

impl Trait for Thing {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::any` contains [the implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#impl-Any):

```
impl<T> Any for T
where
    T: 'static + ?Sized,
```

That means that any type implements `Any` as long as any references it contains are `'static` and the type is sized. Your `Thing` struct meets both of those requirements so it does implement `Any` and your code compiles.